# bind click event to body IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

Im creating an edit dropdown menu and im using the following code to catch clicks outside of the menu. Clicks outside the menu should trigger a close function.
note: this is being used inside a mvc structured app.

All is working until we get to IE8, which says "object doesn't support property or method."
Is they any alternate ways of creating this binding?

```
var that = this
$("body").on('click', that.outsideClickWatch.bind(that) );

outsideClickWatch:function(e){
    console.log("addOutsideClickWatch", this)
    this.remove()
}
```

Comment: IE8 does not support [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). There is, however, a polyfill available in the article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

haha, I've managed to find my own answer :)
I used the following, and all works fine.
Thanks Frederic for the reply though.

```
$(document).delegate('body', 'click', function(e) { that.outsideClickWatch(e) });
```